# Git: How to add git all diff results form one branch in to another?

Tags: git, merge, diff

There was a long development and many commits and pushes to GitLab (I guess this is the same as GitHub). After last merge of **develop** branch in to **master** branch I hade to make a reverse process in master branch. After a wile somehow all latest changes are lost now in both branches. Luckily I have a local copy in my pc with all latest changes. But Git is thinking that this final point where all changes are lost is what I want and I am not able to do anything.
Current situation in my pc:

```
$ git branch -a
  develop
* localdev
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/revert-4b75add3
```

**localdev** is a local branch I have created and it has all latest changes, but Git thinks that they are too old since I made quote some new commit while trying to make things right in **develop** branch which is being pushed in to GitLab.

So I think all I need is to somehow compare **localdev** branch with **develop** branch and add all differences in to **develop** branch. Then i hope I should be able to make a commit and push all changes in to GitLab. How to do that?

Also reset --hard is the hard way and I would prefer not to do it, since it is difficult to track earliest change and also I would lose those commits (I guess), so I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Why not merge `localdev` into `develop`?

Comment: I would love to do that but:
`denis.timofijuk@mypc (develop)    
$ git merge localdev
Already up to date.`

Comment: The all the changes exist in `develop`.

Comment: As I mentioned, git no longer able to track changes, since somehow I mess this up when reverting and then made some more commits on top of that. `git diff develop..localdev` sees all changes correctly. so from my point of view, the best way would be to merge those diff result somehow in to develop, but I don't know how, and can't find useful documentation...

Comment: Do you know how merging works?

Comment: As per this [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), but since `localdev` is now older than `develop`, what ever I do, I always ending up with loosing all my changes...

Comment: At some point between `localdev` and `develop` there has been a commit which undoes the changes. Did you revert at all?

Comment: I did revert via gitlab tool, after that additional `remotes/origin/revert-4b75add3` repo appiered. I can see all gitlab branches that all changes are gone now. Before pulling, I made `localdev` branch. Now `develop` branch is most recent and it has no changes after revert process, but my `localdev` branch has them all. Problem is that in `develop` branch after reverting I did more commits, so now, from git point of view, it looks like I want to have what I have. `localdev` is too old comparing with `develop` which has allready all commits that `localdev` has.

Comment: My question is there a quick way simply force to merge all differences form `localdev` in to `develop` branch and make that as a new commit and look like new changes?

Comment: `simply force to merge all differences` not really. The changes aren't "lost". They're all still there, but you've applied a revert which _undoes_ all those changes. May you share a simplified git tree of `localdev`, `develop`, and this revert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I end up with those commands:

```
(develop)
git reset --hard b8a61c3e
git push -f origin develop
```

Temporary turned off protection for master in gitlab.

```
(master)
git reset --hard b8a61c3e
git push -f origin master
```

Now everything is working fine. Added some rest of the changes manually from my **localdev** branch in to **develop**. Pushed and merged with **master** branch successfully.
Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Thank you @evolutionxbox for the help :) Just to confirm for the future generations if someone would find this case relatable, is **resting hard** up to particular point, the only professional solution working with git?

Comment: No, not really. But it’s good solution depending on the issue. Remember, reset only moves a branch pointer. It’s not magic

Answer (score 0):

To help you look at your commits between two branches, you can compare two branches using `git diff`,

an example
`git diff branch1..branch2`

This example will show you all the commits that “branch2” has that are not in “branch1”

Another way to compare is,

`git diff branch1...branch2`

This is Using `git diff` with three dots, which compares the top of the right branch (the HEAD) with the common ancestor of the two branches.

To view the commit differences between two branches, you use the `git log` command and specify the branches that you would like to compare.

`git log branch1..branch2`

To see the differences written to a file between two branches, use the `git diff` command, specify the two branches and the filename.

`git diff master..feature -- <file>`

If you would like to add a commit from another branch, you can use the `git cherry-pick` command.

Comment: This doesn't solve the question. The OP isn't asking how to diff.